# How do I dump the contents of SYMTAB in gawk?

Tags: awk

How do I dump the contents of SYMTAB in gawk? I've tried things like the following which displays scalars just fine. It also displays the array names and indices, but it doesn't display the value of each array element.

```
for (i in SYMTAB) {
   if (isarray(SYMTAB[i])) {
     for (j in SYMTAB[i]) {
        printf "%s[%s] = %s\r\n", i, j, SYMTAB[i, j]
     }
   } else {
     printf "%s = %s\r\n", i, SYMTAB[i]
   }
}
```

which gives results like:

```
OFS =  
ARGC = 1
PREC = 53
ARGIND = 0
ERRNO = 
ARGV[0] =
```

For example, I would expect to see a value after `ARGV[0]` but I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SYMTAB[i][j]` instead of `SYMTAB[i,j]` - you're using multi-dimensional array syntax in  the loops to access the indices so just keep doing that.

Here's a recursive function to dump SYMTAB or any other array or scalar:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function dump(name,val, i) {
   if ( isarray(val) ) {
        printf "%*s%s %s%s", indent, "", name, "{", ORS
        indent += 3
        for (i in val) {
            dump(i,val[i])
        }
        indent -= 3
        printf "%*s%s %s%s", indent, "", name, "}", ORS
   }
   else {
        printf "%*s%s = <%s>%s", indent, "", name, val, ORS
   }
}

BEGIN {
    dump("SYMTAB",SYMTAB)
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
SYMTAB {
   ARGV {
      0 = <awk>
   ARGV }
   ROUNDMODE = <N>
   ORS = <
>
   OFS = < >
   LINT = <0>
   FNR = <0>
   ERRNO = <>
   NR = <0>
   IGNORECASE = <0>
   TEXTDOMAIN = <messages>
   NF = <0>
   ARGIND = <0>
   indent = <3>
   ARGC = <1>
   PROCINFO {
      argv {
         0 = <awk>
         1 = <-f>
         2 = <tst.awk>
      argv }
      group9 = <15>
      ppid = <2212>
      ...
      strftime = <%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y>
      group8 = <11>
   PROCINFO }
   FIELDWIDTHS = <>
   CONVFMT = <%.6g>
   SUBSEP = <>
   PREC = <53>
   ENVIRON {
      SHLVL = <1>
      ENV = <.env>
      ...
      INFOPATH = </usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info>
      TEMP = </tmp>
      ProgramData = <C:\ProgramData>
   ENVIRON }
   RS = <
>
   FPAT = <[^[:space:]]+>
   RT = <>
   RLENGTH = <0>
   OFMT = <%.6g>
   FS = < >
   RSTART = <0>
   FILENAME = <>
   BINMODE = <0>
SYMTAB }
```

Massage to suit...

Comment: Thank you! That works well until the code hits PROCINFO["argv"] : `fatal: attempt to use array `PROCINFO["argv"]' in a scalar context`. I'll try to use isarray() to detected this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ed Morton. Looks like a recursive process would be required if I needed to support arbitrary levels of nested arrays, but for now this code dumps my gawk SYMTAB without errors:

```
for (i in SYMTAB) {
   if (!isarray(SYMTAB[i])) {
      printf "%s = %s\r\n", i, SYMTAB[i]
   } else {
      for (j in SYMTAB[i]) {
         if (!isarray(SYMTAB[i][j])) {
            printf "%s[%s] = %s\r\n", i, j, SYMTAB[i][j]
         } else {
            for (k in SYMTAB[i][j]) {
               if (!isarray(SYMTAB[i][j][k])) {
                  printf "%s[%s][%s] = %s\r\n", i, j, k, SYMTAB[i][j][k]
               } else {
                  printf "Skipping highly nested array.\r\n"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I added a recursive version to my answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301469/1745001